# Matching non-whitespace characters in Perl 6

Tags: regex, raku

In Perl 6, you can use `<.ws>` to match non-whitespace characters. I want to match any character that doesn't match `<.ws>`, but I don't think I can use `\S` instead because I believe that only matches ASCII spaces while `<.ws>` will match any Unicode space. How do I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A usage of `<.ws>` is a call to the `ws` token that does not capture its result. Its default behavior is:

```
token ws { <!ww> \s* }
```

Which means that:

1. We must not be between two word (`\w`) characters
2. Assuming that is true, there are zero or more whitespace characters at this point

In a given grammar, that can be overridden to specify the "whitespace" of the current language. In the Perl 6 language grammar, for example, `ws` includes parsing of comments, Pod, and even heredocs!

By contrast, `\s` is the character class for matching a single whitespace character, and `\S` means "not a whitespace character". This definition *is* Unicode based; if we do:

```
say .uniname for (0..0x10FFFF).map(*.chr).grep(/\s/)
```

Then we get:

```
<control-0009>
<control-000A>
<control-000B>
<control-000C>
<control-000D>
SPACE
<control-0085>
NO-BREAK SPACE
OGHAM SPACE MARK
EN SPACE
EM SPACE
EN SPACE
EM SPACE
THREE-PER-EM SPACE
FOUR-PER-EM SPACE
SIX-PER-EM SPACE
FIGURE SPACE
PUNCTUATION SPACE
THIN SPACE
HAIR SPACE
LINE SEPARATOR
PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR
NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE
MEDIUM MATHEMATICAL SPACE
IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE
```

Therefore, most probably `\S` is that you are looking for.